# Controlling the format of the text and the overall size of the legend in ggplot - continuous color

Tags: r, text, ggplot2, legend, roc

I am plotting a ROC curve and I have colorized it based on the Cut-Off level.  However the numbers in the legend are too congested with more decimal digits than needed and very large compared to the overall size of the legend. I would like to have one decimal digit, more values, smaller text and larger legend.  But I don't know how to control these parameters.  My code is the following:

```
ggplot(Stats1_glm, aes(x = (1 - Specificity), y = Sensitivity, colour = Cut_Off)) +
  geom_line(size = 2) + theme_economist() + ggtitle("ROC Curve") +
  scale_color_gradient(low="blue", high="red") + xlab("False Alarm (1 - Specificity)") + ylab("Sensitivity (Recall)")
```

[image]

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding this to your plot:

```
 ... + theme(legend.position = 'bottom', # Place the legend at the bottom
        legend.justification = c(1,0), # Position it at the right
        legend.key.width = unit(2.5, 'lines')) # Increase its width to 2.5 lines
```